# Connect to Office365 Outlook with Username and Password using MailKit

Tags: c#, .net, office365, imap, mailkit

I want to connect to user's mailbox by specifying their username and password from my desktop application. But I get this error message:

[image]

> {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"AADSTS50076: Due to a
> configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved
> to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access
> '00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'.\r\nTrace ID:
> b358e7d5-bde2-45a8-9ac7-6a0bdf058100\r\nCorrelation ID:
> 64bee908-3bf6-4691-9737-d78af22b8be4\r\nTimestamp: 2022-08-15
> 13:32:00Z","error_codes":[50076],"timestamp":"2022-08-15
> 13:32:00Z","trace_id":"b358e7d5-bde2-45a8-9ac7-6a0bdf058100","correlation_id":"64bee908-3bf6-4691-9737-d78af22b8be4","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=50076","suberror":"basic_action"}

Am I missing something?
Thank's in advance.

The code looks like this:

```
private async Task ConnectWithOAuth2()
    {
        try
        {
            string ClientId = txtClientId.Text;
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            var scopes = new[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All" };
            var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId).WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs).Build();
            var tokenResult = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text).ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken).Result;

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            var logger = new ProtocolLogger(stream, false);

            using (var client = new ImapClient(logger))
            {
                try
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.Auto);
                    await client.AuthenticateAsync(new SaslMechanismOAuth2(txtUsername.Text, tokenResult.AccessToken));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                    string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    error += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message;

                    MessageBox.Show($"Error: {error}", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show($"Error: {ex.ToString()}", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }
    }
```

My AppRegistration on Azure:
[image]

Authentication:
[image]

API Permissions:
[image]

Comment: You will need to set up an "App Password" https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/manage-app-passwords-for-two-step-verification-d6dc8c6d-4bf7-4851-ad95-6d07799387e9

Comment: @HansKeﬆing, bedankt but I can't find this AppPassword page anywhere. I've setup a user with and without MFA and the same error occured. I use MS-Authenticator app for the MFA.

Comment: On second thought, an app password is for known accounts that can be "hard configured" into an app. You want the user to type in a username and password for their account - that's something else (that I cannot help you with, unfortunately).